# How to set protection level for key ring using java KMS API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-kms

I need to set ProtectionLevel to HSM for a key ring for both cases during creation and for an existing one.

I am trying to use the same way to set this option as any other option:

```
CreateKeyRingRequest.newBuilder().//I see nothing to set ProtectionLevel here.
```

How can I do this using this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HSM ProtectionLevel is not specified on the Key Ring level.

When creating a Key Ring (that is meant to have HSM keys) you just need to take in consideration the [regions supported by the HSM ProtectionLevel](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/locations?&_ga=2.114822465.-730435798.1562054471#hsm_regions)

For the Key Ring creation you just need a parent (location), keyring_id (the name), and the keyRing object, [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/creating-keys#kms-create-keyring-java) gives the following example for Java:

```
/**
 * Creates a new key ring with the given id.
 */
public static KeyRing createKeyRing(String projectId, String locationId, String keyRingId)
    throws IOException {
  // Create the Cloud KMS client.
  try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {

    // The resource name of the location associated with the KeyRing.
    String parent = LocationName.format(projectId, locationId);

    // Create the KeyRing for your project.
    KeyRing keyRing = client.createKeyRing(parent, keyRingId, KeyRing.newBuilder().build());

    return keyRing;
  }
}
```

And then you proceed to create your KMS key, to add the HSM Protection Level you will need to create a new CryptoKey Version Template and set the template to the Crypto Key Builder. This is a sample code which I have already tried and confirmed that it works:

```
  /**
   * Creates a new crypto key with the given id.
   */
  public static CryptoKey createCryptoKey(String projectId, String locationId, String keyRingId,
      String cryptoKeyId)
      throws IOException {

    // Create the Cloud KMS client.
    try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {
      // The resource name of the location associated with the KeyRing.
      String parent = KeyRingName.format(projectId, locationId, keyRingId);
      ProtectionLevel protectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.HSM;

      // creating the template with the right protection level
      CryptoKeyVersionTemplate template = CryptoKeyVersionTemplate.newBuilder()
            .setProtectionLevel(protectionLevel)
            .build();

      // This will allow the API access to the key for encryption and decryption and also the HSM PL.
      CryptoKey cryptoKey = CryptoKey.newBuilder()
          .setPurpose(CryptoKeyPurpose.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT)
          .setVersionTemplate(template)
          .build();

      // Create the CryptoKey for your project.
      CryptoKey createdKey = client.createCryptoKey(parent, cryptoKeyId, cryptoKey);

      return createdKey;
    }
  }
```

The dependencies you will need:

```
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKey;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKey.CryptoKeyPurpose;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.ProtectionLevel;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKeyName;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKeyVersionTemplate;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.LocationName;
```

Comment: I do not see ProtectionLevel setter in CryptoKey builder. I use  group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-kms', version: '1.35.0' dependency which is supposed to be the latest one. Which one did you use?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I didn't actually tried out so I wasn't sure it was going to work that way, on a deeper investigation I found out that you have to set the ProtectionLevel on a "template" first and then set the template to the cryptoKey before building it. I have confirmed this with the Python client API, let me edit the Answer in order to reflect the solution on Java